# Wrong code about c++ char*. Any body view?

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define attr_size 3

int main(){
const char* attr[attr_size];
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<attr_size;i++){

    char* t=(char*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    sprintf(t,"%d",i);
    string temp="attr";
    temp+=t;
    attr[i]=temp.c_str();
    cout<<attr[i]<<endl;
    free(t);
}
for(i=0;i<attr_size;i++){
    cout<<attr[i]<<endl;
}
}
```

And the result is:

```
attr0
attr1
attr2
attr2
attr
attr2
```

Actually, I want to get the result that:

```
attr0
attr1
attr2
attr0
attr1
attr2
```

Maybe something wrong with loop. Anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `c_str` return a pointer that is temporary. So when the loop continue it's iteration the object you got the pointer from is destructed and the pointer is no longer valid, leading to undefined behavior when you later dereference that pointer.

If you want an array of strings, why not declare it as an array of strings?

---

There are also other problems with your code, like you only allocating four bytes for a string that can be 12 (with sign and string terminator) characters.

---

I would suggest you remake your program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>

const size_t ATTR_SIZE = 3;

int main()
{
    std::array<std::string, ATTR_SIZE> attr;

    for (int i = 0; i < ATTR_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        std::istringstream is;
        is << "attr" << i;
        attr[i] = is.str();
    }

    for (const std::string& s : attr)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

The above uses some C++11 features like [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (you can use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead) and [range-base `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (you can use normal iteration instead).

Comment: "as long as the string object itself is valid" Actually the result of c_str() can be invalidated sooner than that. Calling any non-const member function or passing a non-const reference to the string to any library function invalidates the result.

Comment: @bames53 Good catch, I rephrased the answer.

Comment: Sure, but I want to return a const char* attr. Not return a string one.

Comment: @tonymiao When programming in C++, there is no reason to *not* use `std::string` when you need strings. But to accommodate you, you can use `new` to create a character pointer or appropriate size, and then `std::copy` to copy to it. I still recommend using e.g. `std::istringstream` to create the strings though.